# Please help in understanding below regex of hive

Tags: hive

Please help in understanding below regex.

Data:
396124436476092416,"Think about the life you livin but don't think so hard it hurts Life is truly a gift, but at the same it is a curse",Obey_Jony09

Regex for above data:

(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to group the nick wich made the quote, I guess.